# Mule ESB proxy soap webservice

Tags: mule, esb

I want to use Mule ESB as a proxy for my web service. I'm SOATest to simulate the client.
I'm a beginner, i'm using Mule Studio and i don't know which component i should use.
I also need to get arguments values from the soap request.
Any idea?

Here's my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd ">
    <flow name="getValidation_FlowFlow1" doc:name="getValidation_FlowFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8090" path="MyWSService/GetValidation" doc:name="Inbound"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="XX.XXX.X.XX" port="8080" path="ws/MyWSService" doc:name="Outbound"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Proxying Web Services with CXF:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Proxying+Web+Services+with+CXF

Comment: Thank you but I already read the documentation but didn't understand, what i need is may be an example.

Comment: What is that you don't understand?

Comment: I have my WS deployed on JBoss server, and i'm using SOATest to simulare the client, and Mule ESB as an intermediate to route the requests from client to the ws on JBoss server. My ws contains 2 methods, one does not require any arguent(works fine with mule), and the other one requires an arguments of binary type (byte array), i'm not able to read the request scope to extract the arguments and route them.

Comment: Post your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use CXF proxy for a web service proxy
An example of Mule Proxy service will be :-

```
<flow name="ProxyFlow" doc:name="ProxyFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
 <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8086" path="proxy/mainData" doc:name="HTTP" />
 <cxf:proxy-service  namespace="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1" service="MainData"  payload="body" wsdlLocation="MainData.wsdl" doc:name="SOAP"/> 
 <cxf:proxy-client payload="body" doc:name="SOAP" />
 <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="mainData" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" />
</flow>
```

You can modify the flow as per you need

Answer (score 1):

Trying this might help:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <cxf:configuration name="CXF_Configuration" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" initializeStaticBusInstance="true" doc:name="CXF Configuration"/>
    <flow name="soapFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/helloworld" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-service configuration-ref="CXF_Configuration" serviceClass="soap.ISoapInterface" doc:name="CXF"/>
        <component class="soap.HelloSoap" doc:name="Java"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```